# why should a transformation be bijective

Tags: calculus, transformation

Why should $T : D∗ ⊂ R
^2 → D ⊂ R
^2$
 generally be injective and surjective if we want $T$ to represent a
choice of coordinates for the region $D$?

My thinking is that if it's bijective then it'll map exactly to the same spot on the transformation because it's onto and one-to-one. But I feel there's a little more missing and I'm not wording it 100% accurately.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same spot on the transformation".  How does a transformation **have** "spots"?  The crucial point is that a "bijection" has an [b]inverse[/b] transformation.   If we start with p, apply transformation, A, to get Ap, then apply its inverse, $A^{-1}$, we get p back again: $A^{-1}(Ap)= p.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with "same spot".

You always want each point to have coordinates. In your original coordinate system each point had coordinates. You want your transformation to be onto so that each point still has coordinates in your new coordinate system.

You always want every pair of different points to have different coordinates. In your original coordinate system every pair of different points has different coordinates. You want your transformation to be one-to-one so that every pair of different points in the new coordinate system also has different coordinates.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you